# How does res.send work internally? Does it block the event loop?

Tags: javascript, express

Suppose I have a huge JSON response that I need to send back to the client. Will res.send() (suppose if I am using express) block the event loop in node-js? Will event loop be blocked till the time the whole response if written on network?